# Why do I sometimes get this error using SQL in VB.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

This the essence of my code:

```
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    Dim dbSource As String = "Data Source = C:\EBUScore\Pairs\Databases\dBase.mdb"
    Dim dsResults As New DataSet
    Dim daResults As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    Formload:
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        con.Open()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Settings"
        daResults = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        daResults.Fill(dsResults, "Results")
```

It works fine.

When I set sql to "SELECT * FROM Section" it fails on the Fill command with error:
"-      $exception  {"Unspecified error: E_FAIL(0x80004005)"}   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException"

Both Settings and Section are tables in the datafile (an access 2000) file, each with only one record in them.

The Fill works with most tables in the database, but not the section one, nor one other.

I can see nothing different about the tables it works on compared to those it doesn't.

Section Table: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2tBY.png)
Settings Table: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/raTsD.png)

The OleDb I am using is version 7.  Im using the 32 bit version because I have to, and similarly with the Access version.

I tried adding records, different versions of the database, rebooting, removing any spaces in the data... nothing I can think of makes any difference.

Any suggestions as to the cause?

Comment: `SECTION` is a reserved word in MsAccess; could it have something to do with it? try using square brackets around it, like : `[Section]`

Comment: Avoid reserved words as names http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#S

Comment: Thank you,  tinazmu.  I knew about reserved words for field names but never thought about them for table names.  Duuuh!